# Use java class in ColdFusion11 - The java object type is unknown for the CreateObject function

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, railo, cfwheels

I have some code which works under Railo, but am trying to get this particular app working on CF10 and CF11

It's a cfWheels app, and I've got a `BCrypt.class` file in the `/miscellaneous/` directory.

In my `/events/onapplicationstart.cfm` file, I've got:

```
application.bCrypt = CreateObject( "java", "BCrypt", "/miscellaneous/" );
```

This works in Railo; but in CF11 I get

```
The java object type is unknown for the CreateObject function.

Verify the type of your object when creating it and try again. 
Valid Types are : component | java | webservice | dotnet | com | corba | .NET


The error occurred in /Volumes/Documents/blah/public/events/onapplicationstart.cfm: line 8
Called from /Volumes/Documents/blah/public/wheels/global/cfml.cfm: line 111
Called from /Volumes/Documents/blah/public/wheels/events/onapplicationstart.cfm: line 388
6 : 
7 :     // BCrypt library
8 :     application.bCrypt = CreateObject( "java", "BCrypt", "/miscellaneous/" );
9 : 
10 :    // Application Specific settings
```

I assume it's just a syntax thing? Can I call a .class file in this manner on CF10/11 ?

Comment: Adobe CF's `createObject` only has two arguments. The type and the class. The class file itself has to be put in the `cfusion\wwwroot\WEB-INF\classes`  folder

Comment: Ah thanks, needed: this.javaSettings = {
    LoadPaths = ["/miscellaneous"]
  };  and then only use CreateObject( "java", "BCrypt" );

Comment: Reopening because the claim that this question was a duplicate of another wasn't accurate. It was a *similar* situation, but not the same.

Comment: @Neokoenig: you might wanna make your comment into an answer.

Comment: @haxtbh - That was a reasonable explanation (and turned out to be the problem). Next time, post it as an answer so folks can vote on it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah thanks all. As haxtbh said [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30454294/use-java-class-in-coldfusion11-the-java-object-type-is-unknown-for-the-createo#comment48989755_30454294), the problem was

> Adobe CF's createObject only has two arguments. The type and the
>   class.

So I needed to put:

`this.javaSettings = { LoadPaths = ["/miscellaneous"] };`

in /config/app.cfm

and then use

`CreateObject( "java", "BCrypt" );`

in /events/onapplicationstart.cfm

Comment: By default the ColdFusion server caches class file on first load, you can choose to reload fresh copy every time using `reloadOnChange="true"` as  one of the parameters. During development it is really helpful.